# What would be the correct ERD design approach?

Tags: sql, database-design, erd

- Teams can have 1 or more members
- Members can join 1 or more teams
- A member can lead 0 or more teams.
- Each team has a single member leader, where that team leader must be a member of that team. *(eg. If a team had only 1 member, that single member **must** be the leader. If a team had multiple members, 1 of those members OF THAT TEAM **must** be the leader. You can’t have a member leading a team they are not apart of.)*
- A team can only be in a single department.
- A department has 1 or more teams.

I have attempted to design this but I can't figure out how to implement dot point 4 (team leaders). My erd lets any member lead any team. How can I modify it?

Try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouUgQ.png

As you can see, I think my relationship between MEMBER and TEAM is wrong because any member can lead any team which breaks my rules. (Disregard Types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take your requirements one step at a time.

> A department has 1 or more teams.

So, let's create a department table.

```
Department
----------
Department ID
Department Name
...
```

> A team can only be in a single department.

Now, we create a Team table.

```
Team
----
Team ID
Department ID
Team Name
...
```

Department ID is a foreign key back to the Department table.  There's a unique index on (Department ID, Team ID), so you can see the teams in a department.

> Members can join 1 or more teams
>
> Teams can have 1 or more members

First, we need a Member table.

```
Member
------
Member ID
Member Name
...
```

Next, the Team and Member tables have a many to many relationship.  We represent this relationship with a TeamMember junction table.

```
TeamMember
----------
Team ID
Member ID
Join Time Stamp
...
```

The primary key is (Team ID, Member ID).  You will also have a unique index on (Member ID, Team ID).  You get the members of the team from the primary key.  You get the teams that the member belongs to from the unique index.

> A member can lead 0 or more teams.
>
> Each team has a single member leader...

These are the tricky requirements, as you've seen.  Here's one way to model these relationships.

```
Leader
------
Team ID
Member ID
Promotion Time Stamp
...
```

This Leader table has the primary key (Team ID) and the unique index (Member ID, Team ID).  The primary key is just Team ID to enforce the requirement of one leader per team.

There has to be a check that the (Team ID, Member ID) exists on the TeamMember table before the row can be written on the Leader table.  This enforces the requirement that the leader has to be a member of the team.

Otherwise, you could put these columns in the TeamMember table, with the values of the columns null for non-leaders.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without implementing a leader table? If you look at my attempt, can you tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
TEAM
-------
team_id
name
department_id

Person
--------
person_id
name

Team Member
---------------
team_id
person_id
is_leader

Department
-----------
Department_id
name
```